# Count and calculation in a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have 47 set of data to be analysised using Python with the following forma t and I stored the data in 2D array:

```
2104,3,399900 1600,3,329900 2400,3,369000...
```

I use len function to print the item stored in array.  (The previous one has made some mistake and change to following code.)

```
array: with open("abc.txt", "r") as ins: 
substrings = data.read().split()
array = [map(int, substring.split(',')) for substring in substrings]
print(len(array)[0])
```

A part from that I also would like to do some calculation like this for each a, b and c in array like thos format:

```
(2104-500)**2+(1600-500)**2+...
(3-2)**2+(3-2)**2...
```

I wrote:

```
for [a for a, b, c in array] in range (len(array)[0]):
calculation_1 = ([a for a, b, c in array]) - 500)**2

for [b for a, b, c in array] in range (len(array)[1]):
calculation_2 = ([b for a, b, c in array]) - 2)**2
```

How can I improve the code to give the answer I want?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to count? What is your exact expected output? Is your data really just a list containing another single list? Please put together a better [mcve]

Comment: What's `\n` doing there? Do you want to count that as one or two elements? And what's `array:` doing on the first line of your code? And what happened with the indentation? Please correct them, and clarify what you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you have a multi-dimension array ([][]).

The len of array is really one, but if do this

```
len(array[0])
```

is should 95.

Hope it's help

Comment: May be I should give out what I wrote in storing array:

    with open("abc.txt", "r") as ins:
    tmp = ins.read().split(" ")
    array = [i.split(",") for i in tmp]

Comment: @poonck1 modified my answer

Comment: That's not multi-dimensional array, that's just a list with a single element, which also happens to be a list.